# "unexpectedly found nil" out of viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have some outlets in my view and I try to edit them programatically in a function.

Xcode says:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

However, when I edit outlets in `viewDidLoad()` just after `super.viewDidLoad()`, it works like a charm.

With the function :

```
func test(){
    localDeviceNameView.stringValue = "some stuff" //Found nil here

}
```

With `viewDidLoad` :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    localDeviceNameView.stringValue = "some stuff" //Works well  

}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: try `self.localDeviceNameView.stringValue`

Comment: Then you need to post more code, e.g. original line of code, full version of `test()`, the code calling `test()`, anywhere dealing with `localDeviceNameView`

Comment: Does `print(localDeviceNameView)` print nil?

Comment: The code leading up to where you call test() might be interesting...if you're creating a new view controller in order to call it, for example.

Comment: I'll do it. Printing localDeviceNameView do not print nil in viewDidLoad but I get "unexpectedly found nil..." when trying to print localDeviceNameView in my test() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use didSet on your variable. Like this :

```
@IBOutlet var localDeviceNameView : UIView! {
  didSet {
    localDeviceNameView.stringValue = "some stuff"
  }
}
```

What's good with this approach is that you set your stringValue only when the `localDeviceNameView` is set, which is right when it has been loaded from the NIB/Storyboard.

I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: With this, how can I modify my value after this declaration ?

Comment: Then you obviously cannot only use this. I think you have to understand the lifecycle of your UIViewController and how optionals work in Swift. When you try to access an unwrapped optional (cf `UIView!`) it _might_ still be nil (it shouldn't, but it might). So you have to be prepared and try not accessing it directly. Instead, in your `test()` method, try accessing it like `localDeviceNameView?.stringValue = "some stuff"`

Comment: I tried your method and add a "?" in localDeviceNameView?.stringValue = "some stuff" but the value is never modified... :(

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `test()` before views are completely loaded, so they are not exist yet. Do it this way:

```
class MyController: UIViewController {
    var something = ""

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        localDeviceNameView.stringValue = something
    }
}
```

Or call you'r `test()` method only if you sure than all views are loaded (`viewDidLoad()` was called)

Comment: I got a problem with this method, when I modify your variable "something", it doesn't update in the ViewController... Is this linked or not?

Comment: No, my answer is only about why your app crashes. If you need to link them, use didSet as described in @aimak answer